# Problems with running redmine on a server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, rubygems, redmine

I'm trying to install redmine on a Centos server.

I already have PHP and MySQL installed. The domain name of the host where I'm trying to install redmine is http://iteny.com/dev.

It seems that I can't start rails to function properly.

Here is my ruby setup on the server:

- Ruby version 1.8.7
- Rails version 2.3.11
- Ruby gems version 1.6.2
- Rack version 1.1.1
- mySql version 5.1.56

Here is my `dispatch.cgi` file(in `public/` folder):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
require "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/dispatcher"

#require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment" unless defined?(RAILS_ROOT)
# If you're using RubyGems and mod_ruby, this require should be changed to an absolute path one, like:
# "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-0.8.0/lib/dispatcher" -- otherwise performance is severely impaired
require "dispatcher"
ADDITIONAL_LOAD_PATHS.reverse.each { |dir| $:.unshift(dir) if File.directory?(dir) } if defined?(Apache::RubyRun)
Dispatcher.dispatch
```

Here is `environment.rb` file (in `config/` folder):

```
# you don't control web/app server and can't set it the proper way
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'

# Specifies gem version of Rails to use when vendor/rails is not present
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.11' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION

# Bootstrap the Rails environment, frameworks, and default configuration
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')

# Load Engine plugin if available
 begin
 require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../vendor/plugins/engines/boot')
rescue LoadError
  # Not available
end

Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence those specified here

  # Skip frameworks you're not going to use
  # config.frameworks -= [ :action_web_service, :action_mailer ]

  # Add additional load paths for sweepers
  config.autoload_paths += %W( #{RAILS_ROOT}/app/sweepers )

  # Force all environments to use the same logger level
  # (by default production uses :info, the others :debug)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Enable page/fragment caching by setting a file-based store
  # (remember to create the caching directory and make it readable to the application)
  # config.action_controller.cache_store = :file_store, "#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/cache"

  # Activate observers that should always be running
  # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector
  config.active_record.observers = :message_observer, :issue_observer, :journal_observer, :news_observer, :document_observer, :wiki_content_observer, :comment_observer

  # Make Active Record use UTC-base instead of local time
  # config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc

  # Use Active Record's schema dumper instead of SQL when creating the test database
  # (enables use of different database adapters for development and test environments)
  # config.active_record.schema_format = :ruby

  # Deliveries are disabled by default. Do NOT modify this section.
  # Define your email configuration in configuration.yml instead.
  # It will automatically turn deliveries on
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false

  config.gem 'rubytree', :lib => 'tree'
  config.gem 'coderay', :version => '~>0.9.7'

  # Load any local configuration that is kept out of source control
  # (e.g. gems, patches).
  if File.exists?(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'additional_environment.rb'))
    instance_eval File.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'additional_environment.rb'))
  end
end
```

If you need more info about my environment - just ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that I can't start rails to function properly.

What errors do you get? What happens? You neglected to say.

In any case, the easiest way to host a Rails app on Apache or Nginx is to use [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com). Install it and you should be up and running in minutes!

Comment: the problem is that when I test rail server webrick it starts running on http://0.0.0.0:3000 , so I can't test it. And the website shows the folder instead of compiling them into a website. The part about passenger I believe I have them installed. -bash-3.2# find / -name passenger
/home/virtfs/iteny/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/bin/passenger
/home/virtfs/iteny/usr/local/bin/passenger
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/bin/passenger
/usr/local/bin/passenger

Comment: Huh? You can go to localhost:3000 if you want to. But WEBrick is great for development but inadequate for production. Follow the instructions on the Passenger website to get Passenger working.